# Filter Amazon by products surpassing X number of reviews

Tags: amazon

What do you do to filter Amazon by products surpassing X number of reviews?
What do you change in the URL (or elsewhere) to do this?
Any method that works is good.

Answer (score 24):

Append the following to the end of the URL in order to have the items with the most reviews at the top:

**&s=review-count-rank**

It doesn't give exactly the behavior you are requesting, but it should make it easier to find products with a substantial number of reviews.

You can create a bookmark to do this for you by using `javascript:window.location+='&s=review-count-rank'` as the bookmark URL.

Comment: As of Feb 2017 this no longer works.

Comment: It's working for me, on US Amazon.com, April 2017.  I had to take the previous sort argument out of the url: I replaced "&sort=smooth-review-rank" with "&sort=review-count-rank".  Just appending won't work, if there's already a sort earlier in the URL.  In my quick testing, the earliest sort arg consistently took precedence.

Comment: The parameter has changed from "sort" to "s".  Also, as long as one is searching for results from a particular department, appending does work even if there is already another "s" parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible for the following reasons:

1. Amazon only allows sorting when you have selected a `Department`
2. The only review based sorting option available is by `Avg. Customer Review`

There are a few Amazon community threads that have specifically asked for this search ability due to it being available on other sites, but so far no action taken.

Comment: Can you link to some of those threads?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page number in the url and get to relevant reviews more quickly.